# Java, HTML and Android application using the same ServerSocket server

Tags: java, android, html

Is it possible a web html site, android or iOS and desktop client to communicate together using Java Sockets (The server is using ServerSocket)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use an implementation of websockets in the server, instead of pure serversockets, something like : http://jwebsocket.org/ and for the web clients use http://socket.io/ that is a very mature implementation of websockets.

like this you could use the same html that make that communicate with the server using websockets, for pages and also to android runnning embeded in phonegap.

hope it helps.

Comment: I will give android assignment to somebody else, but the server windows application and webpage should be created by me. If i implement the server using websockets how will be done communication with the windows application.

Comment: The window aplication can be developed to work in a browser as well, and by the way there are some easy ways to go websockets as using with tomcat or playframework :) on [tomcat](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/05/01/how-apache-tomcat-implemented-websocket) on [playframework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaWebSockets)